# Search for a String in a column of List of Strings using Spring jpa query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application and I am using Spring Data JPA to query a PostgreSQL database.
I have a column of List type in my database. Now I need a query to search all those rows where my input parameter is present in this list.

eg. I have a column of type List containing any of these values: ["cat","dog","cow"].
I need to find all those rows where "cat" is one among the list.

Can you help me with the format of this query? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could understand, you have a DB table, let's say Sample. Now this table has multiple columns with one column whose values can be either of "cat","dog","cow". Let's assume the column name to be 'sampleName'.

So, in your code you must be having an @Entity class for Sample with @Column sampleName, and a corresponding JPA repository - SampleRepository.

Now, the code for requirement should look like as shown below:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Sample, Long> {
     Optional<Sample> findBySampleName(String sampleName);
}
```

In above JPA repository, I have assumed that you have an @Id field of type Long in your entity Sample. Also, I have made use of method-name strategy. Spring boot will automatically translate this method name to a SQL query at run time like - `SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sampleName = 'cat'`. This value cat will be provided to your repository method as an argument from @Service layer.

Hope this helps!

In addition to this, you can also choose to use the native query approach. Please refer - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query for more details.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply ! But here we need to compare a string in a list. So will this method work?

Comment: Yes, what you can try is - instead of `Optional<Sample> findBySampleName(String sampleName);` use `Optional<Sample> findBySampleNameIn(List<String> sampleName);`, spring should automatically convert this to the query `SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sampleName IN  ('cat', 'cow')`, else you can go ahead with the native query approach and explicitly specify this SQL within @Query in your repository interface.

Comment: this works when I need to check whether any column contains the 'list' that I will pass. But here I need to pass just a string only.

Comment: what is the datatype of your DB column? Can you please share some dummy data, it would be easier to understand the problem that way?

Comment: my column is List<String> Animals. And, I am inputting a string, say, "cat". Then the query or repository method should return all those rows that are having "cat" as one of the elements in this column. I hope this helped.

Comment: Just one confirmation required - is your postresql DB column of type array or simple varchar/text?

Comment: it is simple varchar/text.

Comment: Then my next question is - are you using List<Animal> within entity? Because from what I understand your entity should have an Animal animal reference variable, and we should be good with `Optional<Sample> findBySampleName(String sampleName);`. However, still if you wish to use List<Animal> animals, so what you can do is input cat as a string, add it to a list and then call the repository method `Optional<Sample> findBySampleNameIn(List<String> sampleName);`.

Comment: Please read List<String> animals in my last comment in first line, and String animal in second line. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, please let me know if this suggestion resolved your problem.